# serial port connection - ReadFile always return 4 bytes read

Tags: c++, c, serial-port, uart

I'm trying to read by ReadFile but always get that its read 4 bytes, doesn't mutter how long was the string.

```
UART* uart = (UART*)lpParam;
char TempChar; //Temporary character used for reading
char SerialBuffer[256];//Buffer for storing Rxed Data
DWORD NoBytesRead;
int i = 0;

do
{
    NoBytesRead = 0;
    ReadFile(uart->connHandle,           //Handle of the Serial port
        &SerialBuffer,       //Temporary character
        sizeof(256),//Size of TempChar
        &NoBytesRead,    //Number of bytes read
        NULL);

    //SerialBuffer[i] = TempChar;// Store Tempchar into buffer
    i++;
    if (NoBytesRead > 0)
    {
        char* strMsg = (char*)malloc(sizeof(256 * sizeof(char)));
        SerialBuffer[NoBytesRead] = '\0';
        TRACE("read %d- %s\n", NoBytesRead,SerialBuffer);
        strcpy_s(strMsg, 256,SerialBuffer);
        ControllerPublishMsg(uart->controller, SerialBuffer);
    }
    SerialBuffer[0] = '\0';
```

In case i send string "hh" to connection I'm get output "read 4- hh".
The string is 2 bytes long, but NoBytesRead = 4.

thanks.

Comment: `char* strMsg = (char*)malloc(sizeof(256 * sizeof(char)));` -- This is a huge memory leak.

Comment: The only way `NoBytesRead` can be 4 is if 4 bytes were actually read. If you are sending only 2 bytes, maybe they are being framed with 2 extra bytes (`STX`/`ETX` maybe?) that you are not accounting for.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(256)` defaults to `sizeof(int)` this is four bytes. replace `sizeof(256)` by `256`. Also replace `sizeof(256 * sizeof(char))` by `(256 * sizeof(char))`.

Comment: yes, I fix this mistake, thanks. but still return always 4

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always 1, there is no need to multiply

Comment: Since `SerialBuffer` is a static array, it would be better to use `sizeof(SerialBuffer)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Think about the statement

```
sizeof(256)
```

that you pass as a buffer size.

That expression evaluates to the same thing as

```
sizeof(int)
```

which probably evaluates to 4 on your platform. You'd need to hand over the literal value 256 or better `sizeof SerialBuffer` to `ReadFile`.

And you got the same error in your `malloc` arguments.

Why you are receiving 4 characters when you (think you) are sending only 2 is impossible to see without the code on the sender side. In case `ReadFile` returns 4, it most probably received 4 characters. Due to the messed up buffer size argument, it will however not be able to *receive more than 4 characters*.

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing `sizeof`.

When calling `ReadFile()`, you are using `sizeof(256)` as the number of bytes to read.  A numeric literal is an `int` by default, so you are really using `sizeof(int)`, which is 4 bytes on your compiler.  Get rid of the `sizeof` and just use `256` by itself:

```
ReadFile(uart->connHandle,           //Handle of the Serial port
    &SerialBuffer,       //Temporary character
    256,//Size of TempChar
    &NoBytesRead,    //Number of bytes read
    NULL);
```

Or better, get rid of the `256` and use `sizeof(SerialBuffer)` instead, since it is a static array with a fixed size known at compile time:

```
ReadFile(uart->connHandle,           //Handle of the Serial port
    &SerialBuffer,       //Temporary character
    sizeof(SerialBuffer),//Size of TempChar
    &NoBytesRead,    //Number of bytes read
    NULL);
```

You are making a similar mistake when calling `malloc()`.  `sizeof(char)` is always 1, so you are really calling `sizeof(256)` again.  So again, you can get rid of `sizeof` and just use `256` by itself:

```
char* strMsg = (char*) malloc(256 * sizeof(char));
// or just: char* strMsg = (char*) malloc(256);
```

Although, you are not actually using `strMsg` for *anything* (and you are leaking it), so you should just get rid of it completely.

Try something more like this:

```
UART* uart = (UART*)lpParam;
char SerialBuffer[257];//Buffer for storing Rxed Data
DWORD NoBytesRead;

do
{
    NoBytesRead = 0;
    ReadFile(uart->connHandle, //Handle of the Serial port
        SerialBuffer, //Temporary buffer
        sizeof(SerialBuffer)-1,//Size of buffer minus null-terminator
        &NoBytesRead, //Number of bytes read
        NULL);

    if (NoBytesRead > 0)
    {
        SerialBuffer[NoBytesRead] = '\0';
        TRACE("read %u- %s\n", NoBytesRead, SerialBuffer);
        ControllerPublishMsg(uart->controller, SerialBuffer);
    }
```